# Append action bar items in Android

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I would like to be able to append action bar items from my fragments.

For example in Landscape mode I have a list of items, and if clicked a page of information about that item appears.

The list can be changed by clicking the dropdown in the action bar to select a category of list.

Once a list item is clicked the details fragment is populated. I then want 3 tabs to be appended into the action bar so that the user can select which page of details is shown for that item, namely: "Details (default)";"Map"; and "Features".

In my fragment I can set setHasOptionsMenu(true) and then add the new tabs using the onCreateOptionsMenu call. This however deletes my dropdown which i still want displayed.

How does one simply append ActionBar Items..?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just call the fragment's `onCreateOptionsMenu` from my activity's `onCreateOptionsMenu`. You can add an if statement to decide to call the fragment's version or default call the fragment's `onCreateOptionsMenu` and put the if statement there to decide what to add. then, whenever it needs to change, just call `invalidateOptionsMenu`.

You will probably have to remove the `setHasOptionsMenu` call.

Activity:

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu m)
{
    // insert activity options
    if (needFragmentOptions) {
       fragment.onCreateOptionsMenu(m);
    }
    return true;
}
```

Fragment:

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu m)
{
   // insert fragment options
   return true;
}
```